# URL scheme for Dragon Dictation iphone/ipad app

Tags: iphone, ipad

Looking how to call the Nuance Dragon Dictation iphone/ipad app from another app using the URL schema if available?

Is there a way to access the clipboard on iOS to copy text from Dictation transcribe back into custom app?

Comment: Have you written them to ask if they implement a custom URL scheme?  I'm sure they'd be glad to tell you.

Comment: Yes I have, haven't received a response yet. thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Dragon Dictation, *as of the current version 2.0.4*, does not use a Custom URL Scheme.**

As far as accessing the clipboard, [UIPasteBoard Class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html) is a good place to start.

And for launching the Dictation app *(or any other app that does not have a custom url scheme)* from yours, it's not possible unless there is a URL Scheme in place for the app you want to launch, which as I mentioned above, Dictation does not have.